# Dokku + Rails + Postgresql Error - URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dokku

Hi I am playing around with Dokku on Digital Ocean as an alternative to Heroku. I've read at least 15 guides from Digital Ocean and other blogs. Everything seems pretty straight forward except when I get to running the rails migrations for the first time.

I get the error below...

```
root@jibberishkey:~# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: root:password: (or bad hostname?)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:36:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:270:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:270:in `resolve_url_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:258:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:215:in `resolve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:151:in `block in resolve_all'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:48:in `block in <module:Core>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:285:in `include'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:285:in `<class:Base>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:270:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ancestry-2.1.0/lib/ancestry/has_ancestry.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ancestry-2.1.0/lib/ancestry.rb:4:in `require_relative'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ancestry-2.1.0/lib/ancestry.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have linked my postgresql database with my Dokku app. The only thing I can think is it has something to do with my Dokku config or something to do with my database.yml overriding Dokku config settings. I just can't seem to figure it out.

My database.yml file for production is:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

My dokku config for the app is:

```
DATABASE_URL:      postgres://root:password:/db
NO_VHOST:          1
rails_env:         production
```

I can confirm that the password in `config` is the same as what is in the db:migrate error. This is also the same as what is in my Dokku app `export` which I find by running this series of command from the server...

```
docker run -i -t dokku/app_name /bin/bash
export HOME=/app
for file in /app/.profile.d/*; do source $file; done
hash -r
export
```

Anyone able to shed some additional light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a recent issue with the dokku-pg-plugin, as I was able to create a database/wire the app up with the database fine with an older version of the dokku-pg-plugin.

I've filed an issue with the project team, who can advise: https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-pg-plugin/issues/69.

Answer (score 1):

I think the database URL is incorrect. It should look like `postgres://root:password@localhost/db`